# Add 2D arrays using a recursive method

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, recursion

I would like too add two 2D arrays using a recursive method with this code:

```
public static int[][] x(int one[][],int two[][],int i,int j,int sum[][]){
    if(i==one.length-1 && j==(one[0].length-1)){
        return sum;
    }
    else if(j>one[0].length){
        j=0;i++;
        return x(one,two,i,j,sum);  
    }
    else {
        j++;
        sum[i][j]=one[i][j]+two[i][j];
        return x(one,two,i,j,sum);  
    }
}
```

but, this code doesn't work correctly. I did not understand.

Thanks!

Comment: Please check [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question. "This code doesn't work" is not a correct question.

Comment: can you provide and example?

Comment: You asked a [nearly identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48637399/18157) earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any reason why you try to do it recursively? Iteratively is much easier in this case:

```
for (int i = 0; i < one.length; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < one[i].length; j++)
        sum[i][j] = one[i][j] + two[i][j];
```

Of course you can get the same result recursively. Judging from your code I assume you want to call it like this: `x(one, two, 0, 0, new int[one.length][one[0].length])`.

Your main problem is that you move the indices already before doing the calculation and you return too early.

```
public static int[][] x(int one[][],int two[][],int i,int j,int sum[][]) {
    if (j == one[i].length) {
        if (i == one.length - 1)
            return sum;
        i++;
        j = 0;
    }
    sum[i][j] = one[i][j] + two[i][j];
    return x(one, two, i, j + 1, sum);
}
```